# "bin/sh: dart: command not found" in VSCode

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I was trying to run flutter and dart using tutorials but I'm stuck with this error:

```
/bin/sh: dart: command not found
```

This is my user settings in VS Code:

```
"dart.flutterSdkPath": "/Users/sam/Desktop/Codeground/App_development/flutter/bin"
```

And in .bash_profile this is what is written:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/sam/Desktop/Codeground/App_development/flutter/bin"
```

I already tried adding another path to the dart-sdk/bin sub-folder as well but to no avail. I'm running MacOS Ventura 13.0.1

I'm trying to run:

```
dart "/Users/sam/Desktop/Codeground/App_development/Projects/sample_application/lib/main.dart"
```

Comment: Are you using Windows, Mac or Linux system? Also what is the command that you are trying to use?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `$HOME`, make sure rest of the path.

```bash
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/Desktop/Codeground/App_development/flutter/bin"
```

Comment: Still the same error

Comment: make sure to restart the shell, Also can you include the device info, then just run `dart` to check the env. And `echo $PATH` to the env paths

Comment: When I run and debug it works as expected, was this how I was supposed to do?